# Feferman's universes for proof assistants?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, type-theory, proof-assistants

This question was prompted by a discussion from [another MO question about the consistency of ZFC](https://mathoverflow.net/a/437200).  There are some mathematicians who are [comfortable with ZFC but uneasy with large cardinals](https://mathoverflow.net/a/382670).  For them, it may be unsettling that Mizar assumes infinitely many inaccessibles, and that Lean's dependent type theory makes a similar tacit assumption. Basically, this is because they appeal to Grothendieck universes.

Now, there is an alternative: Feferman's universes achieve most of what a "practicing mathematician" wants from Grothendieck's universes, but has the advantage of being conservative over ZFC. So here's my question:

> Suppose we wanted a proof assistant to avoid going beyond the consistency strength of ZFC, while retaining essentially all the functionality of something like Mizar or Lean.  Could this be done using the Feferman-universe idea?  How difficult would this be to implement and what would be the tradeoffs?

(Maybe this question belongs on the [proof assistants StackExchange](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/), but that site seems to be more of a help desk for existing proof assistants than a forum for broader mathematical questions like this one.)

Comment: I am not an expert on type theory, but I know that universes in Martin-Löf Type Theory (MLTT) are given with *finitely* many (introduction and elimination) rules, and adding (a form of) extensionality with LEM to MLTT results in a theory whose strength is more or less similar to that of ZFC. That seems to mean Feferman's idea would not work under type-theoretic setups.

Comment: I monitor proof assistants on a regular basis. Enough people there are willing and able to answer theoretical questions, there's just too few people asking. Anyway, the Feferman trick already plays a role there but at the next level up, as I tried to explain here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380539/are-we-sure-the-calculus-of-inductive-constructions-and-zfc-plus-countably-many/418133#418133

Comment: Perhaps a short reminder of what a "Feferman universe" is, would be in order?

Comment: Feferman's original paper is [Set-theoretical foundations of category theory](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0059148) but I haven't found a non-paywalled link. Mike Shulman's paper [Set theory for category theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1279) contains a readable summary; see pages 24-25 in particular.

Comment: @Tymothy Chow Maybe you should also mention the 2004 paper of Feferman  <a href="https://math.stanford.edu/~feferman/papers/Ambiguity.pdf">
Typical Ambiguity: Trying to Have Your Cake and Eat it too</a>. There he describes $ZFC/U_{<\omega}$ which seems more advanced than 1969 $ZFC/s$.